# How to open this file?? or Instead Downloading, show preview in new window?? I have pdf file

Tags: javascript

This code saves file dirctly, I want to preview my pdf file
Note: I have content which is plain/text so first I have to create pdf file then open or preview

```
function download(filename, text) {
 var element = document.createElement('a');
 element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' +  encodeURIComponent(text));
 element.setAttribute('download', filename);

 element.style.display = 'none';
 document.body.appendChild(element);

 element.click();

 document.body.removeChild(element);
 }
```

Comment: Embed pdf using [object tag](http://joliclic.free.fr/html/object-tag/en/object-application.html#pdf)

Comment: I dont have file location,
just have content in plain text format

Comment: check my post below. Ideally you should have your data encoded properly

Answer (score 0):

Embed pdf using object tag

```
var objectPDF = document.createElement("object");
objectPDF.data = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' +text;
objectPDF.type = 'application/pdf';
document.body.appendChild(objectPDF);
```

You can also use `iframe`

As mentioned in comment if you just want to show your file in a new window, remove `doanload` attribute and add `target="_blank"`. [Sample here](https://jsbin.com/tihigezute/1/edit?html,js,output)

```
function download(filename, text) {
 var element = document.createElement('a');
 element.setAttribute('href', 'data:application/pdf;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  element.setAttribute('target','_blank');

 element.style.display = 'none';
 document.body.appendChild(element);

 element.click();

 document.body.removeChild(element);
 }
```

To make it further more simpler use `window.open()` instead of a temp link. [Sample here](https://jsbin.com/difuhuzahi/edit?js,output)

```
function viewFile(filename, text) {
  window.open('data:application/pdf;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
}
```

Comment: I want to open pdf in new tab, I have div tags so pdf looks so small

Comment: In that case try snippet in [this code](https://jsbin.com/tihigezute/edit?html,js,output). Adding `target="_blank"`; Let me know if it works, i will update my post

Comment: that code works but there should be "data:application/pdf"
And one more problem is in "link location bar" It shows whole content in plain text format

Comment: `data:text/plain` was just to show a working example you can replace it with `data:application/pdf`. Yes the content will be shown as the part of link if you are opening it using a link in new tab. Use object tag as mentioned in my post to avoid such behavior and append object tag in some popup of your own

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function download(filename, text) {
 var element = document.createElement('a');
 element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));

 element.style.display = 'none';
 document.body.appendChild(element);

 element.click();

 document.body.removeChild(element);
 }
```

Comment: This is nice, but wont it open the file in the same window replacing all the content. You should add `element.setAttribute("target","_blank")`;

Answer (score 0):

Use embed element for holding pdf files

```
var pdf = "pdf file link here";

    $('<div/>')
        .html('<embed class="fullFrame" ' +
              'type="application/pdf" ' +
              'src="' + pdf + '"></embed>')
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            modal: true,
            height: 400,
            width: 400,
            title: "Resume"
        });
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but I dont see jquery tag in the question

Comment: there isnt
but I just wanted to suggest the OP towards using embed  
probably they should be able to use some document.getElementById and change its src using javascript :)